# Cross-browser JS inconsistencies

Tags: javascript, jcrop, nyromodal

I have a PHP script that allows image upload. I modified it slightly to load newly uploaded image into a modal window in order to allow manual crop, if needed.

It seems I got it working in FireFox (all the way until actual crop).
IE throws an error:

> "Object does not support this property or method"

and Opera just chokes and does not know what to show...

I am out of ideas what is causing this. Here's the page, click "Add New Scene" and submit some image to upload to view described behavior:

Any insight will be highly appreciated.

---

UPDATE: decided to go with a different class.

Comment: This calls for basic debugging. Which line does the error appear in? What does the line contain?

Comment: Related: http://www.jonathanboutelle.com/how-to-debug-javascript-in-internet-explorer

Comment: It points to Line 48 Char 1 in jquery.min.js, not very useful, hah? Sorry I wish I could give a better lead.

Answer (score 0):

javascript libraries are not properly loaded.

Check the view source that the jquery file is included.

Check the jquery version also.

Ok Now

```
var addthis_config = {
    ui_cobrand: "SlateCast.com",
    ui_header_color: "#ffffff",
    ui_header_background: "#cc0000",
    services_compact: "aolmail, hotmail, live, typepad, ymail, google, squidoo, stumbleupon, delicious, reddit, googlebuzz, digg, linkedin, favorites, more",
    services_exclude: "print",
    data_track_clickback: true
}
```

This is your js . got it from your source only

semi colon missing or something !!

Check

Comment: It is the latest stable version: jquery-1.4.2.min.js and yes, I can see it through view source link.

Comment: Tried commenting it out -- no change.

Comment: There's no need for semi colon here. It's just a list of params in an array format.